# Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views to be show in Bottom

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, google-play

I created a Swipeable Tab view Like in Google play using http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ this code. But my requirement is the Action Bar Tabs should show in the Bottom of the View. Is there any way to doing this...

Answer (score 0):

Split action bar provides a separate bar at the bottom of the screen. This option will be useful when you want to display the action items at the bottom of the screen by leaving some space on the title bar.

To enable split action bar add **uiOptions=”splitActionBarWhenNarrow”** to all the  tags **or** to the  tag directly in AndroidManifest.xml file. Also we need to add  with the value android.support.UI_OPTIONS to support older version below **API level 14.**

```
<activity
    android:name="info.androidhive.actionbar.LocationFound"
    android:label="@string/activity_location_found"
    android:parentActivityName="info.androidhive.actionbar.MainActivity" >
    <!-- To support below API Level 14 -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
           android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
</activity>
```